# windows mouse pointer, icons and some text became big

Tags: windows, icons, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm working with a windows server 2012 remotely. Other people using it too.

Mouse pointer,Desktop icons and some text became big and this makes work hard.
This is not resolution problem.

[image]

How I can fix this problem?

UPDATE:
Scaling in Display Setting is disable for remote sessions:
[image]

Comment: Someone may have adjusted display scaling so see if it is set to a number higher than 100%: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2953978/displays/use-windows-10s-individual-display-scaling-to-perfect-your-multi-monitor-setup.html

Comment: I couldn't found any same option in windows server 2012

Comment: How about Control panel -> Appearance -> Display -> Scaling:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmCsG.png

Comment: Scaling in Display Setting is disable for remote sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Signed out and Signed In Again and problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you press the Ctrl key while you scroll with the mouse, that changes the zoom of the actual Window.

That works on the desktop too. So, while in you desktop press Ctrl and scroll and you can adjust the zoom of the icons of your desktop.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But this trick only works for icons not texts or mouse pointer. Texts in some of apps became big too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I connected a mouse to the remote PC. It solved the problem and worked for me.